# Ler arquivo exportado do Microft SQL 2016

Tags: sql, r

Recebi um arquivo exportado do Microsoft SQL 2016 que tem extensão .txt e o mesmo com .csv e tem essa cara:

[image: Amostra dos dados]

​
Procurei, mas ainda não achei nada, alguém tem alguma expriência em importar esse arquivo para o R?

Um simples read.csv por exemplo não funciona

Answer (score 1):

Em teoria, qualquer arquivo .txt pode ser importado para dentro do `R`. Tente rodar o comando

```
dados <- read.table(file="NomeDoArquivo.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

em que

- `file="NomeDoArquivo.txt"` é o nome do arquivo a ser importado
- `header=TRUE` informa que `NomeDoArquivo.txt` possui um cabeçalho. Se `NomeDoArquivo.txt` não possui cabeçalho, altere o argumento para `header=FALSE`
- `sep="\t"` é o separador de colunas do arquivo. Como `read.csv` não está funcionando, chuto que o separador de colunas é uma marca de tabulação. Outras opções comuns para `sep` são `,`, `;` e `" "` (espaço).

Por fim, rode

```
dim(dados)
str(dados)
```

e veja se o número de linhas e colunas reportado é o esperado e se o tipo de dado em cada coluna está correto. Se tudo der certo, o conjunto de dados foi importado corretamente. Se não der certo (ou se o código acima não funcionar), volte aqui para tentarmos descobrir juntos o que que fazer.

Comment: Valeu Marcus Nunes, eu já tinha tentado com o read.csv, o problema é que a partir de um ponto, como aqui: [{id:14974258949854043,component:datePicker,index:0,label:Veuillez   ele le tudo como uma variável só:

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi se a minha sugestão resolveu o problema.

Comment: A sugestão que o Marcus deu era um caminho, e eu iria até sugerir que caso não desse, tentar a função `read.fwf`. Só que depois do seu comentário de ler um campo como uma variável só eu comecei a questionar quais seriam as variáveis do seu problema. O `read.txt` ou similares vai entender cada coluna da figura como uma variável. Caso o seu problema seja que as variáveis estejam somente na parte do `[{id:14974258949854043,component:datePicker,index:0,label:Ve‌​uillez` aí seria uma outra forma para resolver seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael Cunha, o problema é exatamente descobrir qual commando para ler isso, na verdade ele começa com uns numeros, depois vem o colchete e as chave e parece que há um label separado por ':' do valor, mas não tenho certeza ainda: 001115,9156BFA5-4A4B-4028-9F13-769DECDC01D8,Questionnaire,2017-06-21 08:36:49.000,2017-06-21 12:00:00.000,1,NULL,"[{""id"":""14974258949854043"",

Comment: Oi Marcos Nunes, não resolveu, ela le o arquivo mas não separa os campos, veja meu último comentário

Comment: Então a situação é bem mais complicada. Qual deve ser o resultado da leitura do campo `[{id:14974258949854043,component:datePicker,index:0,label:Ve‌​‌​uillez`? O que isto significa? São quantas colunas diferentes? Seriam quatro (`id `, `component`, `index` e `label`)?